# Firefox configure one hop (double) proxy

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firefox, proxy, squid

In my office network, all traffic goes through a squid proxy (proxy A). I have another squid proxy (proxy B) on a vps.

I can browse internet fine using proxy A when on office network and proxy B when I connect from my home.

However, I want to use proxy B from my office network. That is, I would like to tell firefox  to use proxy B, but via proxy A. How to achieve this?

I am fine with any alternate web browser / custom script that would allow me to do so as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i once tried to do the same thing... i never made it, but my alternate solution was to open an ssh tunnel to the server hosting proxy B (through proxy A obviously because i had to), and with this tunnel I was able to do whatever i need to...

(i had to use proxytunnel http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/ because my proxy A needed NTLM authentication and proxytunnel was the only one i manage to auth with...)